# calculate sum of squares using shell script in perl/awk

Tags: awk, perl

I have 2 files as below.

**file1**

```
0.34
0.27
0.32
```

**file2**

```
0.15
0.21
0.15
```

Now, I would like to calculate the sum of squares between each column. For example,

```
[(0.34 - 0.15)^2 + (0.27 - 0.21)^2 + (0.32 - 0.15)^2 ] / 3
```

Where **3** is the total number of lines in the file. I will be having same number of lines in both the files.

I have come up with the below bash script which works perfectly fine, but I want to know if there is some other easier way.

```
#! /bin/bash   
sum=0.0
while true; do
  read -r lineA <&3
  read -r lineB <&4
  if [ -z "$lineA" -o -z "$lineB" ]; then
    break
  fi
diff=$(bc <<< "scale=5; $lineA - $lineB")
square=$(bc <<< "scale=5; $diff*$diff")
sum=$(bc <<< "scale=5; $sum+$square")
done 3<file1 4<file2
filelen=`wc -l file1 | cut -f1 -d' '`
final=$(bc <<< "scale=5; $sum/$filelen")
echo "$final"
```

Is there a simpler way in `awk` or `perl`?

**EDIT**

I had 2 million rows in my input file and the input file actually contained scientific numbers like below.

```
3.59564e-185
```

My script as well as the suggested answers failed on scientific numbers. However, I could make my script in the question work when I changed the scientific numbers to `10^` notation.

I converted my input file as below.

```
sed -e 's/[eE]+*/\*10\^/' file1 > file1_converted
sed -e 's/[eE]+*/\*10\^/' file2 > file2_converted
```

Now, the suggested 2 answers failed giving me the error message as `Nan`. My script seemed to work but for 2 million rows it is taking a long time to execute.

Is there any efficient way to make it work?

Answer (score 7):

One way to do it using `paste` since your files have the same number of lines.

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '{s += ($1-$2)^2}; END{print (s+0)/NR}'
0.0228667
```

Comment: it worked for general cases. But when I had 2 million rows with scientific numbers unfortunately it did not work. Even after converting to `10^` notation, this command did not work. I have modified my question with the errors am facing.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'FNR==NR { file1[NR]=$1; next; }; { diff=$1-file1[FNR]; sum+=diff^2;}; 
  END { print sum/FNR; }' file1 file2
```

Comment: Please see my edit. Your command worked for general cases. But not for my case.

Comment: @Ramesh My `awk` does recognize such numbers: `echo 0.05 3.59564e-185 | awk '{print $1 * $2}'`; `echo 0.05 3.59564e-85 | awk '{print $1 * $2^2; }'`

Answer (score 1):

With your big float data, you can use `perl` with its `bignum`:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | perl -Mbignum -anle '
    $sum += ($F[0] - $F[1])**2;
    END {     
        print $sum/$.;
    }                
'
0.02286666666666666666666666666666666666667
```

Comment: thanks. Should I convert it to `10^` notation or I can use this `perl` command on scientific numbers as well?

Comment: Don't need to convert to `10^`. Make sure you have enough memory and with 2 milion rows, it will take long time to run.